# Cannot use spring's embedded message broker for test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-test

I have following component which is using for sending messages to broker (kafka) and also receiving by StreamListener of spring-cloud. Now I need write test where I send message to embedded broker and also I verify that message is received. Here is my component:

```
@Component
public class FooMessaging {

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    public void sendMsg(FooMsg msg) {        
        // some logic
        processor.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg).build());
        // some logic
    }

    // and handler:

    @StreamListener(value = Processor.INPUT)
    public void handler(FooMsg msg) {
       threadSafeMap.put(msg.getId(), msg.getBody());
    }
}
```

config:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class BrokerConfig {
}
```

And here is my sample test where I tried just tests if my autowired is not null and next I want send message to output channel and receive it over embedded message broker of spring cloud test support. Can you tell me how to do that? I just tried run following code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {BrokerConfig.class})
public class BokerTest {
    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
        assertNotNull(processor);
    }
}
```

but I got this exception and I am not able to continue:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:137)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:66)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:138)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:124)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:238)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1232)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:76)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:58)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.apply(ZkUtils.scala)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:171)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicsIfAutoCreateEnabledAndAdminUtilsPresent(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:153)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:119)
    ... 43 more
```

I also have this dependency in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

EDIT:
I find out when I have running docker image with zookeeper and kafka test works. So problem is spring don't use embedded but looking for remote.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test with Kafka embedded broker you may want to check how tests/configuration is done in [KafkaBInder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka).
Simply adding `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` won't work.

However, you can also add the new (simplified) TestBinder. 
Here is instructions on how to configure it in your Pom/Gradle https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/pull/1241

NOTE: Remove spring-cloud-stream-test-support from your POM/Gradle

. . and here is the code snippet for your test:
```
public class DemoRabbit174ApplicationTests {

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(new Class[] {MyConfiguration.class, 
            TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class}, new String[] {});
    InputDestination source = context.getBean(InputDestination.class);
    source.send(new GenericMessage<byte[]>("Hello".getBytes()));
}

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public static class MyConfiguration {

    @StreamListener("input")
    private void sink(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

}
```

Comment: See [this sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/testing-samples/test-embedded-kafka) which shows how to test with an embedded Kafka broker.